# copy THEN paste FILES in terminal

Tags: terminal, copy-paste

Is there any package that I can use to copy one (or more) file/folder THEN paste into another directory?
I am using Ubuntu, and I have the standard terminal + Terminator.

For example, I am looking for a functionality like:

```
Folder1$ COPY a.txt
Folder1$ cd ../Folder2
Folder2$ PASTE (a.txt -- optional)
```

Thank you! I just hate to keep referring to the whole path every time!

Answer (score 1):

Here's my dumb way to do this, you can add them to your rcfile:

```
copy(){
    test -z $1 && echo "No file input!" && return
    test ! -e $1 && echo "File not exist!" && return
    export orig_path="$PWD/$1"
    export orig_name="$1"
}
paste(){
    test -z $orig_path && echo "No copied file!" && return
    if [ "$#" -lt 1 ];then
        dist_name="$PWD/$orig_name"
        if [ -d $orig_path ];then
            cp -r $orig_path $dist_name
        else
            cp $orig_path $dist_name
        fi
        echo "$orig_name pasted."
    else
        dist_name="$PWD/$1"
        if [ -d $orig_path ];then
            cp -r $orig_path $dist_name
        else
            cp $orig_path $dist_name
        fi
        echo "\"$1\" pasted."
    fi
}
```

This doesn't copy any data to the clipboard, since you want to do this only for not referencing folders, and this works for copying folder as well.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `clipboard-files` here: https://github.com/larspontoppidan/clipboard-files

It uses `xclip` to interface the desktop environment clipboard and provides handy commands like `ccopy` and `cpaste` that does exactly what was asked for here. As the desktop environment clipboard is used, the commands interact with the copy/pasting in file managers and other programs that use the clipboard for files. At least it works on Gnome-like desktops.

Full disclosure, I wrote the script after giving up finding something like it out there :)

Answer (score 1):

I just created a tool that can do this.

https://github.com/FynnSu/savepath

Use the sap command followed by a list of file paths (either relative or absolute) to add paths.

To use one of the saved paths just write pap followed by the command you want to use the path in and hit enter. You will then be prompted to confirm the command, and can use the arrow keys to modify the command: left/right moves the path insert location and up/down switches between different saved paths.

Answer (score 0):

This terminal command should work for files:

```
cp a.txt ../Folder2/a.txt
```

And for folders:

```
cp -R myFolder ../Folder2/myFolder
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but this is copy AND paste in the same command. I need copy THEN paste

Comment: Why would you need that?

Comment: If that's the case try this: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/15318/using-terminal-to-copy-a-file-to-clipboard

Comment: 1- I need it because: (a) I hate referencing folders and I prefer to navigate to the destination; (b) it should be doable because ubuntu file manager does it automatically.
2- The link you sent is a MAC environment. The equivalent to it in Ubuntu is XClip, and technically, it copies the CONTENT or data of a file to the clipboard. It does not work with folders.